# laravel execute subquery query and get count

Tags: laravel, select, subquery

how select query like this in Laravel -

```
Select t.*, count(Select * from persons person 
where person.user_id = t.id) from users t
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
DB::table('users')
  ->selectRaw('*, count(SELECT * FROM persons WHERE persons.user_id = users.id)')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score -5):

In my opinion to count data of other table, you can use join table combining with group. It's same as your query. You can do this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('persons', 'users.id', '=', 'persons.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', count(persons.user_id))
            ->groupBy('persons.user_id')
            ->get();
```

I hope this can help you.